# Custom TensorFlow RNN Cell with Tuple Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to create a custom RNN cell in TensorFlow that accepts a tuple as an input, but I'm running into the problem that the parent class `BasicLSTMCell` requires that inputs be two-dimensional:

```
# Inputs must be 2-dimensional.
self.input_spec = base_layer.InputSpec(ndim=2)
```

How can I get around this restriction? I can't add the logic to handle the tuple in the `call()` method because execution never reaches the method - a dimensionality check raises an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found this problem as well. There is a bug in the tensorflow platform. You can solve by changing the get_step_input_shape function in the recurrent.py file. Just add [0] to the end of this line: nest.map_structure(get_input_spec, input_shape))